# mysql ST_WITHIN with POLYGON

Tags: mysql

I am not able to any return from the following test.

mysql version: 5.6.16 (win32)

```
SELECT  (ST_WITHIN(GeomFromText('POINT(110.341903 1.558064)'), ST_GeomFromText(
         "POLYGON((1.558467 110.341781 1.558081 110.342317 1.557764 110.34175 1.558467 110.341781 ))"
         )))
```

I just want to see is that point within the polygon.  From the map the point is within, What I did wrong?

I did a try on, also doesn't work

```
mysql> SET @g1 = ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(110.341903 1.558064)');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @g2 = ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((1.558467 110.341781 1.558081 110.3423
17 1.557764 110.34175 1.558467 110.341781 ))');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT ST_WITHIN(@g1,@g2);
+--------------------+
| ST_WITHIN(@g1,@g2) |
+--------------------+
|               NULL |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't add commas after each pair of values in definition of polygon.

You have:

```
POLYGON((1.558467 110.341781 1.558081 110.342317 1.557764 110.34175 1.558467 110.341781 ))
```

It should be:

```
POLYGON((1.558467 110.341781, 1.558081 110.342317, 1.557764 110.34175, 1.558467 110.341781 ))
```

Additionaly, I suspect that you have swapped coordinate values because clearly `POINT(110.341903 1.558064)` cannot be located inside that polygon, while `POINT(1.558064 110.341903)` can.

This works without problems:

```
SELECT (
  ST_WITHIN(
    GeomFromText(
      'POINT(1.558064 110.341903)'
    ), 
    ST_GeomFromText(
      'POLYGON((1.558467 110.341781, 1.558081 110.342317, 1.557764 110.34175, 1.558467 110.341781 ))'
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: I tried to translate it into table.

`code`
update abc set location=GeomFromText('POINT(1.5580641 110.341903)') where id = 1;

SELECT  *
         FROM abc
         WHERE (ST_WITHIN(abc.location, ST_GeomFromText(
         "POLYGON((1.558467 110.341781, 1.558081 110.342317, 1.557764 110.34175, 1.558467 110.341781 ))"
         )))
`code`

it gives me empty roll.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.  My mistake.  Its correct, I updated the wrong database and query another database.